# Updating handlers in QueueListener after it is created

Tags: python, logging, handler

is there anyway to change the number/config of handlers in the QueueListener after it is created?

I could recreate it every time I need, but that doesn't sound very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handlers are accessible through a property called `handlers`. Simple example that shows how to remove the last handler:

```
sh1 = logging.StreamHandler()
sh2 = logging.StreamHandler()
ql = logging.handlers.QueueListener(queue.SimpleQueue(), sh1, sh2)
ql.handlers = ql.handlers[:-1]
```